# Python: reading and printing a binary file

Tags: python

I have a binary file and I want to read the data, one byte at a time, printing each byte as it runs.

The code I have so far is:

```
f = open("test.dat", "rb")
try:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != "":
        print byte
        raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
        byte = f.read(1)
finally:
    f.close()
```

However, this is not giving me expected results. Basically, I want to print out a number between 0 and 127 for each byte. However, the first print gives me a smiley face symbol, which I know is not within the first 128 entries in ASCII. Therefore, it seems I am printing out more than just a byte - even though I have specified only to read 1 byte in f.read.

What's going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the output of `print ord(byte)` ?

Comment: By the way, don't use `try/finally` here, use a [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Answer (score 8):

The smiley face is Windows codepage-850's character 1 (white face) or 2 (black face), so that's all OK.

[image]

If you want to print the number, just use

```
print ord(byte)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well. But I'm just wondering what the difference is between ord(byte) and int(byte)? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try it? `int(byte)` only works if `byte` is one of the characters `"0"` through `"9"`.

Comment: "Did you try it" isn't really very helpful. I've found the difference very confusing too, given that many examples on SO show using `int()` to do this conversion.

Answer (score 2):

What `read(1)` returns is a single-character string. Try:

```
print ord(byte[0])
```

Or as well you can do

```
print ord(byte)
```

as Python has no separate character type, and `ord()` works with single-char strings.